# refresh controller freeze after changing tap tab bar quickly

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I use refresh controller. It works well when I tap the tab bar item after the refresh animation completely end. But if I tap the bar item very quickly before the animation done, it will be freeze. I try to use refreshControl.endRefreshing() in viewDidApper. I try to use refreshControl.endRefreshing() in viewWillDisappear, too. This bug still happen. Below are my code and the snapshot.

snapshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTdgd.jpg

demo video: https://youtu.be/cZMurwiwfjI

```
let refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
@IBOutlet weak var myScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var noDataView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "MessageListCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MessageListCell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self       
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

    self.tableView.isHidden = true
    self.myScrollView.isHidden = false
}
```

I put refreshControl.endRefreshing() here. It seems no work.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    if !oneReload {
        getList()
        oneReload = true
    }
}
```

I also try to put refreshControl.endRefreshing() before adding the subview. It still no worked.

```
private func getList(){

   if self.viewData.count > 0{
     self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
     self.tableView.isHidden = false
     self.myScrollView.isHidden = true         
     self.tableView.reloadData()
   }else{
     self.myScrollView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
     self.myScrollView.isHidden = false
     self.tableView.isHidden = true
   }   
}

@objc func refresh(){
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.getList()
}
```

I think this will happen because the view controller been freeze before changing the tabbar selected view. Next time I back to the view.It show with the freeze animation. Can I solve this issue? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: did u try to place it in the viewDidDisappear

Comment: @jbiser361 Yes,I try to put endRefreshing() in viewDidDisappear. The issue still happen. I update a demo video. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: try making it hidden

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your refresh method on the main thread.

```
@objc func refresh(){
    DispatchQueue.async.main {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.getList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this issue still happen after I use your approach. I update a demo video. I think this can help you to understand the situation I meet. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Hum I think I get the problem. For your refreshControl you need to bind action on getList() and inside the getList() method, after your else,, at the end of your method call endRefreshing.

Comment: and remove self.refreshControl.endRefreshing() from viewDidAppear

Comment: Can you explain more about the comment? I use refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged) in viewDidLoad. The refresh function include getList function. The issue is approach when the animation didn't finish yet. So I think the controller didn't call the binding function.

Comment: The declaration is correct, your refreshControl need to be added on the viewDidLoad method. The approach is, you start a refresh (activity control appearing) everything reload, then the refresh control disappear. What's the point of being an animation if datas or reload aren't done yet ?